# Shortest path in Time dependent network in Python

Tags: python, routes, shortest-path, timedelta, temporal

I have a time expanded graph e.g. consider a network of 10,000 nodes where at t=13:00:00 links between nodes 1-2, 10-13 exists and at 13:00:03 some other links. Each link has a Travel time.
I want to find shortest path between a given o-d pair at a timestamp(e.g. shortest path between 1 -10 starting at 13:00:00.

I tried Multigraph of Python but it says that the shortest path feature is not defined for such Graphs in their website. Moreover, I want to input the departing time also. Any idea how I can do this in python ?